# how to go to link after verify is complete?

Tags: javascript, html

i have this code

`<a href="about.html" onclick="verify()"><span>go</span></a>`

and i want when the verify complete as `true` it's go to `about.html`

if not give `alert` with the wrong and `don't` go to `about.html`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a href="about.html" onclick="return verify();"><span>go</span></a>

function verify(){
    var isValid = false; // do your check!
    if (!isValid) {
         alert("some message");
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

Comment: i tried it with no work it keep navigation to `about` if `true` of `false`

Comment: @Buffon: don't forget to add the `return ` to the `onclick` attribute.

Comment: thanks very much it works..but i want to ask a question why we add `return` on `onclick` attribute?

Answer (score 2):

The function verify should return false if you want to stop the link navigation. return true to continue to about.html.

e.g.

```
 function verify(){
    //verify stuff
    if(it is verified){
        return true;
     }else{
        alert("problems");
        return false;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If `verify` returns `true`, it will jump the link. If it returns `false`, you will not go to about.html. You can choose to show an alert if you like. It will not influence this flow.